# Pthreads: Worker Thread Waits Forever for Signal From Controller Thread

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, data-structures, pthreads

I'm working on a thread scheduling assignment, which consists of a controller thread indicating when a worker thread ("bus") is allowed to leave its station. There would normally be many bus threads fed through a text file that could be at one of several stations, but this problem can be seen by creating a single bus with pre-defined values (id, direction, loading and crossing time) and a single station, which I've done here to minimize the code.

The general workflow of each bus thread is as follows:

1. Create a structure which contains a con_var, lock, and flag
   (initialized to 0). This will be pushed to the first queue.
2. Create a Bus class object with id, direction, etc. This will be pushed to 
   the second queue. Both queues represent the same station.
3. Wait for signal from controller to begin loading. Once received, sleep for 
   the bus' loading time.
4. On wakeup, push the created structure and the bus object to their queues
5. Wait for crossing signal from controller...

This last part is the issue; although I've verified that the controller IS continuously sending the signal, the thread will not stop waiting. It just hangs forever and never gets to cross. I'm not sure if I'm sending the wrong signal or if the problem is something else, but I'm quite stuck and would appreciate any available help. **The first 2 code windows are for the controller and bus functions respectively, which are the heart of the issue and what I'm hoping someone is willing to look at**. The third is the header for my structures/classes, and final is the entire compilable main function if necessary.

## busController()

```
void *busController (void* n){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&load_lock);
    int remainingBuss = totalBusCount;
    readyToLoad = true;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&loadReady_cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&load_lock);

    while (true){
//if there's a single bus in all queues (the first of several scenarios to come)
            if(loadedBusCount == 1){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&SouthCondition.front().lock_var);
            SouthCondition.front().flag = 1;
            pthread_cond_signal(&SouthCondition.front().cond_var);
//NOTE: printing &SouthCondition.front().cond_var shows different address than bus thread is waiting for
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&SouthCondition.front().lock_var);
            }

    }
}
```

## busFunction()

```
void *busFunction (void* t){

    CondStruct condition; //Will be pushed to the first queue, contains cond_var, lock, and condition flag for the bus
    pthread_mutex_init(&condition.lock_var, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&condition.cond_var, NULL);
    condition.flag = 0;

    struct BusStructure *data = (struct BusStructure *) t;

    //create Bus object which takes its data from the bus structure for easy access inside queue

    Bus bus(((BusStructure*)t)->dir, ((BusStructure*)t)->id, ((BusStructure*)t)->loadTime,
    ((BusStructure*)t)->crossTime);

    //wait for signal to begin loading from controller thread

    pthread_mutex_lock (&load_lock);
    while(readyToLoad == false){
            pthread_cond_wait(&loadReady_cond, &load_lock);
    }
    cout << "BUS HAS BEEN UNLOCKED AND CAN PROCEED TO START LOADING" <<endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&load_lock);

    usleep((((BusStructure*)t)->loadTime)*1000000); //sleep to simulate load time

    //Bus has now loaded, add to relevant queue
    pthread_mutex_lock(&busLoading_lock);
    cout << "Pushing bus " <<bus.getID()<<" to queue"<<endl;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&busToQueue_lock);
    SouthCondition.push(condition);
    SouthBus.push(bus);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&busToQueue_lock);

    loadedBusCount++;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&busLoading_lock);

    //Wait for crossing signal from controller (THIS IS THE PROBLEM AREA, BUS WAITS FOREVER)

    pthread_mutex_lock(&condition.lock_var);
    while(condition.flag == 0){
    cout <<"Thread "<<bus.getID()<<" is now waiting for " << &condition.cond_var << endl;
            pthread_cond_wait(&condition.cond_var, &condition.lock_var);
    }

    cout <<"TIME TO CROSS, WHICH ISN'T IMPLEMENTED YET. THIS PRINTOUT IS THE SUCCESS." <<endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&condition.lock_var);
}
```

## StructClassMCVE.h

```
#ifndef StructClassMCVE_H
#define StructClassMCVE_H

struct BusStructure{
    public:
    char dir;
    int id;
    double loadTime;
    double crossTime;
};

class Bus{
    public:
    char dir;
    int id;
    double loadTime;
    double crossTime;

    Bus(char d, int i, double l, double c){
            dir = d;
            id = i;
            loadTime = l;
            crossTime = c;
    }

    ~Bus(){}

    char getDirection(){return dir;}
    int getID(){return id;}
    double getLoadingTime(){return loadTime;}
    double getCrossingTime(){return crossTime;}
};

struct CondStruct{
    pthread_cond_t cond_var;
    pthread_mutex_t lock_var;
    int flag;
};

#endif
```

---

## mainMCVE.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<cstring>
#include<sstream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<queue>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include <vector>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fstream>
#include<ctype.h>

#include"StructClassMCVE.h"

using namespace std;

int totalBusCount;
int loadedBusCount = 0;

pthread_cond_t loadReady_cond;
bool readyToLoad = false;

pthread_mutex_t load_lock;
pthread_mutex_t busLoading_lock;
pthread_mutex_t busToQueue_lock;

queue<CondStruct> SouthCondition;
queue<Bus> SouthBus;

void *busFunction (void* t){

    CondStruct condition; //Will be pushed to the first queue, contains cond_var, lock, and condition flag for the bus
    pthread_mutex_init(&condition.lock_var, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&condition.cond_var, NULL);
    condition.flag = 0;

    struct BusStructure *data = (struct BusStructure *) t;

    //create Bus object which takes its data from the bus structure for easy access inside queue

    Bus bus(((BusStructure*)t)->dir, ((BusStructure*)t)->id, ((BusStructure*)t)->loadTime,
    ((BusStructure*)t)->crossTime);

    //wait for signal to begin loading from controller thread

    pthread_mutex_lock (&load_lock);
    while(readyToLoad == false){
            pthread_cond_wait(&loadReady_cond, &load_lock);
    }
    cout << "BUS HAS BEEN UNLOCKED AND CAN PROCEED TO START LOADING" <<endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&load_lock);

    usleep((((BusStructure*)t)->loadTime)*1000000); //sleep to simulate load time

    //Bus has now loaded, add to relevant queue
    pthread_mutex_lock(&busLoading_lock);
    cout << "Pushing bus " <<bus.getID()<<" to queue"<<endl;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&busToQueue_lock);
    SouthCondition.push(condition);
    SouthBus.push(bus);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&busToQueue_lock);

    loadedBusCount++;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&busLoading_lock);

    //Wait for crossing signal from controller (THIS IS THE PROBLEM AREA, BUS WAITS FOREVER)

    pthread_mutex_lock(&condition.lock_var);
    while(condition.flag == 0){
    cout <<"Thread "<<bus.getID()<<" is now waiting for " << &condition.cond_var << endl;
            pthread_cond_wait(&condition.cond_var, &condition.lock_var);
    }

    cout <<"TIME TO CROSS, WHICH ISN'T IMPLEMENTED YET. THIS PRINTOUT IS THE SUCCESS." <<endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&condition.lock_var);
}

void *busController (void* n){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&load_lock);
    int remainingBuss = totalBusCount;
    readyToLoad = true;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&loadReady_cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&load_lock);

    while (true){
//if there's a single bus in all queues (the first of several scenarios to come)
            if(loadedBusCount == 1){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&SouthCondition.front().lock_var);
                        SouthCondition.front().flag = 1;
            pthread_cond_signal(&SouthCondition.front().cond_var);
//NOTE: printing &SouthCondition.front().cond_var shows different address than bus thread is waiting for
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&SouthCondition.front().lock_var);
            }

    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    totalBusCount = 1;
    pthread_t thread[2];

//create bus thread

    struct BusStructure *busEntry = new struct BusStructure;

    busEntry -> id = 0;
    busEntry -> dir = 'S';
    busEntry -> loadTime = 0.6;
    busEntry -> crossTime = 1.2;

    pthread_create(&thread[0], NULL, busFunction,(void *) busEntry);

//create controller thread

    pthread_create(&thread[1], NULL, busController,NULL);

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the MCVE exhibits the problem, can't we lose the other files?  Why are you initialising the mutex and condition variable from within one of the threads (`busFunction`)?  You've no way of knowing that will happen before the other thread is trying to access them.

Comment: Which "other files" are you referring to? As for the mutex and condition variable initialization, as each thread requires its own unique copies of these, how would there be any other way to do this than initialize from within the function? I used the thread here as a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37019144/control-each-thread-by-its-own-condition-variable-c

Comment: Just had a quick look - where are you initializing the busLoading_lock and busToQueue_lock? Also - have you run this in gdb? That should quickly tell you where it's hanging...

Comment: These are both global variables at the top of mainMCVE.cpp. And no, I'm afraid I'm not familiar with gdb.

Comment: @MMMMMCK: *"Which "other file" are you referring to?"* - your question has busFunctoin and busController in two named, indented blocks, then mainMCVE.cpp repeats all the code for both.

Comment: Yes, this was in case someone had a question about any part of the code that wasn't included in those two blocks. The blocks are more readable, the full main file is more thorough, I figured it would be more helpful to have both.

Comment: @MMMMMCK Yes - but you still need to initialize them with either pthread_mutex_init, or statically by assigning PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER to them. And regarding gdb - it's not really hard to learn the basics, and it'll save you a ton of time with stuff like this. There are lots of tutorials around ;)